# Looping Inside Stack Widget Flutter

Tags: loops, flutter, layout, stack, widget

I have a problem right now
I need to use StreamBuilder to get all the data from my database and then build every data into a widget with position in it.
Because I use position, I need to use Stack as a parent widget.
But the problem is I can't use ListView builder to loop the snapshot data
Is there any way to loop inside so I can return the widget?

```
                                   Stack(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Container(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                          ),
                                            StreamBuilder(
                                              // initialData: {'handler': "handler"},
                                              stream: mapPlacementStream.stream,
                                              builder: (context, snapshotPlacement) {
                                                dataPlacement = snapshotPlacement.data;
                                                if(!snapshotPlacement.hasData){
                                                  return const Text('Connecting...');
                                                }
                                                else{
                                                  return new StreamBuilder(
                                                  // initialData: {0: true},
                                                  stream: mapStateStream.stream,
                                                  builder: (context, snapshotState) {
                                                    dataState = snapshotState.data;
                                                    if(!snapshotState.hasData){
                                                      return const Text('Connecting...');
                                                    }
                                                    else{
                                                      return ParkPainter(
                                                            1, 
                                                            20, 
                                                            20,
                                                            1, 
                                                            true
                                                          );
                                                  }
                                                );
                                                }
                                              }
                                            ),
                                        ],
                                    )
```

On Else I return the ParkPainter to see if it can print the ParkPainter (the widget with position)
It works

Comment: With the example of ListView builder, the builder needs you to "return" the value, so it knows that the "return" value which is a widget, will be build by the loops

Comment: I want to build a Container with the data I get from my Stream

Comment: No the Container comes from the StreamBuilder, it goes with the name ParkPainter